# How to view data in loopback's memory db?

Tags: node.js, memory, loopbackjs

Is there a way to check/browse data in memory connector of loopback

or

Is there a db client available to connect to loopback's memory db and browse its data?

I searched the [loopback's site](https://docs.strongloop.com/) but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a direct answer but maybe you can use [file options](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Memory+connector) `"file": "mydata.json"` like this so that you can open it and view the data store in there?

Bad thing about this is it only save data to file on application exit.

Update

- Data is stored in a JSON format
- Recent data is prepended to the top

Comment: Thanks, it works. Please update your answer to add this info - `Data is stored in a JSON format. ` and `Recent data is prepended to the top`